# Ubuntu Docker Container Permission Denied StreamWriter

Tags: docker, ubuntu, .net-core

I have a pretty simple docker container that runs a .Net Core 5 application. The docker file for the image is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-focal 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus

WORKDIR /dockercontext
COPY . ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll"]
```

The host is running Ubuntu 20.04.

Part of my application has a simple output to a file method:

```
 public async static Task WriteTextToFileAsync(string fileName, string text, bool append)
 {
   CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(fileName);
   using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(fileName, append))
   {
     await outfile.WriteAsync(text).ConfigureAwait(false);                
   }
 }
```

The process is failing with the following error:

```
[System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/mount/output/Runs/27a02b9a-179d-4794-a9de-8e4153fa0b41/Messages/message.xml' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CloseStreamFromDispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at PKTestingSharedLibrary.HelperFunctions.WriteTextToFileAsync(String fileName, String text, Boolean append)
```

The docker container has a few mounted drives:

```
sudo docker container create --name worker -v /mount/qzhzntgf6r5uaxjp2vov/prdct-other/prdct-test/configs:/mount/configs -v /mount/qzhzntgf6r5uaxjp2vov/prdct-other/prdct-test/catalogs:/mount/catalogs -v /mount/sgbatchprdctother/output:/mount/output imagename:tag
```

These mounted drives are Azure Storage file shares mounted to the Linux host. I've docker container exec'd into the running container and I'm able to cd to the Messages folder and I'm able to write simple files there using bash. I checked all running processes inside the container and I can see my app running as the root user:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  4.5 3582108 184988 ?      Ssl  Sep02   0:22 dotnet myproject.dll
```

I'm not sure what else to try. My linux host and the docker container are not running SE Linux. The file gets created at the location but has no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a bunch more searching I came across this issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42790#issuecomment-817758887

> I ran into this and wasn't in a position to change all our code that
> writes files to CIFS shares. I investigated different kernel versions
> as it appeared to happen after we upgraded the OS on our hosts. It
> turned out to be introduced in kernel v5.5.1, in fact this commit:
> torvalds/linux@d067799. I managed to work around it by mounting our
> cifs shares using the nobrl option. From
> https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs:
>
> nobrl Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is
> necessary for certain applications that break with cifs style
> mandatory byte range locks (and most cifs servers do not yet support
> requesting advisory byte range locks).
>
> After remounting shares including this option the problem went away.

Mounting my azure file share with the nobrl command fixed my issue.